# How to get the type of error to use in error handling

Tags: go, error-handling

If you do this:

```
_, err := http.Get("google.com")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

you get the output:

```
2021/08/05 15:42:18 Get "google.com": unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

I'm wondering how do I get the type of error, so I can handle the error like so:

```
if errors.Is(err, "unsupported protocol scheme") {
    //add protocol scheme to url string
}
```

I've tried fmt.Printf("%#v", err), which gives:

```
&url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"google.com", Err:(*errors.errorString)(0xc000098c40)}
```

fmt.Printf("%T") gives:

```
*url.Error
```

Edit: If you're downvoting, I'd really appreciate a comment with your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
var e *url.Error
if errors.As(err, &e) && strings.HasPrefix(e.Err.Error(), "unsupported protocol scheme") {
    //add protocol scheme to url string
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/VKpMfrBp_EF

Note that comparison against non-standardized strings should not be considered future-proof. For example if a future version of Go decides to change the wording of that error message your code will break.

Although Go does promise compatibility across versions, I don't think that that promise extends to string content.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just came upon an interesting section in this article: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully called "Never inspect the output of error.Error" which gives some other reasons on why you shouldn't change the behavior of your program based on the error string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `err.Error()` to return string.
and check if it contiane a spicifice keys, something like this:

```golang
if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    switch {
    case strings.Contains(err.Error(), "connection refused"):
         // handle connection refused. for example:
         cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "service", "mariadb", "start")          
         _ = cmd.Run()
       
    default:
         log.Println("unknown kind of this error", err)
    }
}
```

in your case you can try somthing like:

```golang
err := http.Get(url)

if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "unsupported protocol scheme") {
    //add protocol scheme to url string
}
```